# How do I fix my code for moving an object along a plane in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to move an object along a plane in Unity3D, so that the object's y position is clamped to the plane and the x and z move according to the mouse moving side to side/up and down.

It seems like the code is *almost* there, but there is a scaling issue with the mouse's up/down movement.

Moving the object side to side works properly and looks like so:
[The mouse behavior is shown in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJIty.png)
Moving the object forward and back, or up and down with the mouse, is scaled incorrectly and looks like so:
[The mouse is at the x, but the capsule is not aligned with the mouse.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0UBQ.png)
Ideally, the mouse should correspond with the position of the object better, like so:
[The y of the mouse and the far-backness of the object should align.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u30B2.png)

I believe there is a scaling error in the code for moving the mouse up and down.

The code looks like this.

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.localPosition = GetMouseAsWorldPoint() + mOffset; 
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        mZCoord = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;
        mOffset = gameObject.transform.localPosition - GetMouseAsWorldPoint();
    }

   
    private Vector3 GetMouseAsWorldPoint()
    {
        Vector3 mousePoint = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePoint.z = mZCoord;
        mousePoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePoint);
        mousePoint.y = plane.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y;
        return mousePoint;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your having those problems because of the camera's rotation.

This code creates a plane at 0, 0, 0 and shoots out a ray from the camera and gets where it intersects with the plane.

```
void Update()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
    float distance = 0;
    if (plane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
    {
        transform.position = ray.GetPoint(distance);
    }
}
```

https://answers.unity.com/questions/269760/ray-finding-out-x-and-z-coordinates-where-it-inter.html